# Clear Parse Installation at the time of app uninstall

Tags: android, parse-platform, installation

Develop an App in which i use Parse as a back-end service. I want to do something at the time of uninstall but it looks like it is impossible through android. Hence i thought to remove parse installation at the time of uninstall and changed the info of linked user for that installation.

Can I remove parse installation object at the time of app uninstall?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Every time you do a fresh install, a parse installation record is created. So basically the parse installation is unique. There is no need to clear the parse installation.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I know fresh installation is created but here concern is different. I need to handle something at the time of uninstall hence i need to remove the installation info.

Comment: What is that something. Your question is unclear. We cannot help you till you state the exact problem.

Comment: I need to toggle login_bit at the time of uninstall for the current user which i linked with the current installation. Hence if i able to remove installation object which then trigger the toggling of bit

Comment: Add the toggle bit to the parse user table.  That way you will be able to do whatever you want to.

Comment: toggle bit is added to user table itself. But i need to handle the uninstall scenario  how to do? i.e. why i am exploring installation info.

Comment: One thing you can do is save the installation token in the user table. And on login check your current installation token with the one stored in the user table.  If they are different it means that the user has done a fresh install

Comment: I also need to handle one user login only on one device. Suppose if some user login from different device then your proposed technique assumes this is the fresh installation and login which doesn't satisfy my criteria and user are logged in from two different devices.

Answer (score 0):

sorry man, parse installation is not unique, only parse object created is unique but what to do with that, i think they can do more than this, like they can take android device unique id when user installs app, so this will also restrict duplicate entry next  time user installs same app...